# how to get a list of the installed audio players?

Tags: java, android, audio-player

Is it possible to get a list of the installed audio players?

I guess I could do that as following.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

But I got nothing.

Could anyone help me? T_T

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); 
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : apps) {
        //process list here
    }
```

Comment: I got this message. 12-20 17:52:41.623: W/ContentResolver(2548): Failed to get type for: content://media/internal/audio/media/1 (Unknown URL : content://media/internal/audio/media/1)

Comment: @yong: tested and edited my answer, please check now

Comment: thank you for your reply. but Im not trying to launch activity. I wanna get a list of audio players. :(

Comment: And I edited my code. I could get a list which has audio/* in an intentfilter. but I would like to a list of audio players. is it possible?

Comment: @yong yes, it's possible, new edit for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This code sniper lets you choose at first from you're installed audio players and then gives opportunity to play music from them.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   intent.setType("audio/mpeg3");
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Im not launching the player. I just want to get a list of players.